# Excluding all tables with XPath and Scrapy

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I have the following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Scrapy</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table style="border: #ffffff 0px solid" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
         <tr>
            <td align="center">
               <div style="margin-top:7px;margin-bottom:7px;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;font-color:white" width="100%">
                  Scrapy Rocks
               </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="margin-top:25px">
         <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top"></td>
            <td valign="top">
               <font size="-1">
                  <div style="margin-right:10; margin-top:5; text-align: right">
                     <a href="/aaa.html" target="_top">AAA</a> | 
                     <a href="/bbb.html" target="_top">BBB</a> | 
                     <a href="/ccc.html" target="_top">CCC</a>
                  </div>
               </font>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top">
               <div>
                  <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">
                    <img src="/images/a.jpg" border="0" vspace="0" width="100" height="100" valign="middle"/>
                  </a>
                  <a href="/index.html">
                    <img src="/images/aaa.gif" border="0" vspace="0" width="100" height="100" valign="middle"/>
                  </a>
               </div>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
               <div style="margin-right:10; margin-top:5; text-align: right"></div>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <hr size=1>
      <h2 style="margin-top: 36px; margin-bottom: 24px">
         Abcd efgh for 2017
      </h2>
      Part 1 | 
      Part 2 | 
      Part 3 | 
      Part 4 | 
      <a href="#">A very bold title</a>
      <hr size="1" style="margin-top: 36px; margin-bottom: 24px">
      <a name="part1"></a>
      <h3>Part 1</h3>
      <ul>
      </ul>
      <a name="part2"></a>
      <h3>Part 2</h3>
      <ul>
      </ul>
      <a name="part3"></a>
      <h3>Part 3</h3>
      <ul>
      </ul>
      <a name="part4"></a>
      <h3>Part 4</h3>
      <ul>
      </ul>
      <div style="margin-top: 36px; margin-bottom: 24px">
         <a name="non_rep"></a>
         <h3>Abcd efgh</h3>
      </div>
      <b>January 2017</b>
      <ul>
         <li>
            <b>Part1 1</b>
         </li>
         <ul>
            <li>
               <a href="/cgi-bin/o.pl?file=/a/1.htm">Title 1</a>
            </li>
            <br>
            <li>
               <a href="/cgi-bin/o.pl?file=/a/11.htm">Title 2</a>
            </li>
            <br>
         </ul>
         <li>
            <b>Part1 2</b>
         </li>
         <ul>
            <li>
               <a href="/cgi-bin/o.pl?file=/a/2.htm">Title A</a>
            </li>
            <br>
            <li>
               <a href="/cgi-bin/o.pl?file=/a/22.htm">Title B</a>
            </li>
            <br>
         </ul>
         <li>
            <b>Part1 3</b>
         </li>
         <ul>
            <li>
               <a href="/cgi-bin/o.pl?file=/a/3.htm">Some text 1</a>
            </li>
            <br>
            <li>
               <a href="/cgi-bin/o.pl?file=/a/33.htm">Some Text 2</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </ul>
      <b>February 2017</b>
      <ul>
         <li>
            <b>Part1 1</b>
         </li>
         <ul>
            <li>
               <a href="/cgi-bin/o.pl?file=/b/1.htm">Title 1</a>
            </li>
            <br>
            <li>
               <a href="/cgi-bin/o.pl?file=/b/11.htm">Title 2</a>
            </li>
            <br>
         </ul>
         <li>
            <b>Part1 2</b>
         </li>
         <ul>
            <li>
               <a href="/cgi-bin/o.pl?file=/b/2.htm">Title A</a>
            </li>
            <br>
            <li>
               <a href="/cgi-bin/o.pl?file=/b/22.htm">Title B</a>
            </li>
            <br>
         </ul>
         <li>
            <b>Part1 3</b>
         </li>
         <ul>
            <li>
               <a href="/cgi-bin/o.pl?file=/b/3.htm">Some text 1</a>
            </li>
            <br>
            <li>
               <a href="/cgi-bin/o.pl?file=/b/33.htm">Some Text 2</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </ul>
      <b>March 2017</b>
      <ul>
         <li>
            <b>Part1 1</b>
         </li>
         <ul>
            <li>
               <a href="/cgi-bin/o.pl?file=/c/1.htm">Title 1</a>
            </li>
            <br>
            <li>
               <a href="/cgi-bin/o.pl?file=/c/11.htm">Title 2</a>
            </li>
            <br>
         </ul>
         <li>
            <b>Part1 2</b>
         </li>
         <ul>
            <li>
               <a href="/cgi-bin/o.pl?file=/c/2.htm">Title A</a>
            </li>
            <br>
            <li>
               <a href="/cgi-bin/o.pl?file=/c/22.htm">Title B</a>
            </li>
            <br>
         </ul>
         <li>
            <b>Part1 3</b>
         </li>
         <ul>
            <li>
               <a href="/cgi-bin/o.pl?file=/c/3.htm">Some text 1</a>
            </li>
            <br>
            <li>
               <a href="/cgi-bin/o.pl?file=/c/33.htm">Some Text 2</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </ul>
   </body>
</html>
```

What i need here is to extract the text between the body tags (using Scrapy xpath) but I don't want the tables text at all.

What I tried to get all the text was:

```
def parse(self, response):
    """
    -*-
    """

    item = DummyItem()

    title = response.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
    body = "\n ".join(
        response.xpath(
            '//body//*[not(self::script or self::style)]/text()'
        ).extract()
    )

    item['title'] = title
    item['body'] = body

    yield item
```

Whit the above stanza, I managed to extract all the text, tables inclusive, which I don't want.
Then I replaced the "body" with:

```
body = "\n ".join(
    response.xpath(
        '//body//*[not(self::table or self::script or self::style)]/text()'
    ).extract()
)
```

It didn't do the job. Still extracting the tables text.

Any ideas on how to tackle it?

Comment: If undesirable items located on the 1st level under body change a little your xpath `'//body/*[not(self::table or self::script or self::style)]/text()`

Comment: I think you want ancestor-or-self::table to exclude any table and any child of table

Answer (score 1):

You want *"all text nodes that are not in a `<table>`"*, or *"all text nodes that do not have a `<table>` ancestor"*.

That's `/html/body//text()[not(ancestor::table)]` in XPath.

```
 text_nodes = response.xpath("/html/body//text()[not(ancestor::table)]").extract()
```

now you only need to strip whitespace from the resulting items and remove empty strings from the list.

```
body = "\n ".join(filter(None, map(str.strip, text_nodes)))
```

Comment: Your proposal worked but not 100% in a slightly different case. The problem for me is that I can't think in xPath terms. So, are there any good resources to learn xPath properly?

Comment: I am afraid you have to find those yourself. There are plenty of tutorials, blog posts and documentation to read and countless questions here on SO that deal with all facets of specific issues. It should not be too hard to pick up the basics in a couple of hours, IMHO.